# invalid LOC header in android studio

Tags: android

I create an new project in Android studio use default options. Then I got an error:

> Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed
>
> Error:Cause:invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Use menu `Build>Rebuild Project` or `Build>Clean Project` will get same error.

Why?

Comment: have you find any solution for this ? i am getting the same error :  Error:Cause: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Comment: Build->Clean Project worked for me

Answer (score 3):

This is how I fixed "Error:Cause: invalid LOC header (bad signature)"

I fixed this problem by deleting **`caches folder`** which is located inside **.gradle folder** but it is not the ones inside the android project.

I deleted the one inside my home directory (C:\Users\{my name}\.gradle)

Steps:

1. Locate your home directory

**Click File -> New -> import project -> Right Click or press ctrl + R-> Home Directory -> Copy URL (This is your home directory)**

2. Open any folder and paste your Home URL
3. Look for ".gradle" folder
4. Look for and delete "caches" folder
5. Run your project from android studio.

Causes for this error:
For me, my PC was out of memory while updating Android Studio from 3.3.1 to 3.4.1.

After I restarted PC, some of locally saved files were corrupted.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is usually caused by a corrupt locally cached jar. Delete the jar that is giving the error and then rebuild.

Comment: Please either describe the answer in detail or use the comment

Answer (score 2):

in android studio command line run

```
./gradlew --stop
```

and then build the project it'll work fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem on this process

first, you need to be close android studio then
find the `.gradle` folder then enter the `wrapper` then enter the `dists` after entering the `dists` folder you look like `gradle-X.X-all`
then you move or delete `gradle-X.X-all` all file from `dists` folder then reopen android studio and enjoy it.

This process 100% working for me

Answer (score 1):

Go to gradle-wrapper.properties And upgrade your gradle version.
In my case Older Gradle version is

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1.1-all.zip

And After Changing version this is worked for me.

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip